# iCE40LP1K FPGA - Performing an analog to digital function (Power monitoring) without an ADC

Tags: digital-logic, pcb-design, analog, fpga, embedded

I'm using [iCE40LP1K](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1qse16qxjnqkmao/FPGA-DS-02029-3-7-iCE40-LP-HX-Family-Data-Sheet.pdf?dl=0) FPGA and I wanted to create a block that is responsible for doing a fast power down of all devices on the platform when the 12V is shut down due to powercut.

Whcih means, when 12V is OFF, we want the FPGA to perform a fast reaction to turn off all the "Enables" signals for DC-DC's, LDO's, and other devices on platform.

Although the FPGA is supplied from 3.3V which is created from the 12V_Main, there is still a lot of capacitors on platform that need to discharge until the 3.3V gets affected from 12V shutdown.
here is the Lattice FPGA [Schematic Design](https://www.dropbox.com/s/amfyuih3xh34p6o/LATTICE%20ICE40LP1K.pdf?dl=0)

[image]

My question is, how can I tell FPGA, using VHDL code to perform a certain function when the 12V goes below a specific logical value?
It looks like that I need to find out what is the ViH and VoL for the FPGA IO's.
I have added two resistors where the voltage at PIN 84 would be around 3.3V, and I thought that If 12V goes down, then 3.3V will be smaller and that would be logical "0" for the FPGA.

but I did that assuming that for example 3.29 is considered 0V which is wrong.
what is right value of resistors I need to make such a function based on the IO's operation voltage range?

Note: I know such function be achieved better by using ADC. but this FPGA doesn't have one and we want to achieve this goal by simpler means.

Comment: Why do you need the FPGA to sit in between? Why can't you just use a voltage divider and have the 12V signal shut down everything? (Possibly through a BJT to get correct polarity.) Is it some extreme cost- or space constrained application, or what's the reason?

Comment: Also, it would seem that you are actually looking for an analog comparator rather than an ADC. There are dedicated "brown out protection" IC you can use for such, they were very common before all MCUs got brown-out protection internally. Search for "3.3V voltage supervisors".

Comment: Does the +12V and +3.3V rails share the same ground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a digital pin and a resistor divider, a schmidtt trigger or other buffer would be good to clean up the signal (a schmidtt trigger is either low or high) before you send it into the FPGA. If this isn't done you could introduce [metastablity](https://www.nandland.com/articles/metastability-in-an-fpga.html) into the FPGA as FPGA signals need to either be low or high, not in the middle which makes both transistors turn on at the same time). A resistor bridge can give you voltages that are in the threshold range and not low or high and should be avoided piping in their voltages straight into FPGA's. Make sure you also mind the [voltage levels](https://hackaday.com/2018/08/14/behind-the-pin-logic-level-outputs/) as the [inputs can be selected](https://www.latticesemi.com/-/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/ApplicationNotes/PT/sysIOUsageGuidelinesforLatticeDevices.ashx?la=en) on FPGA's (never used ice40 so I can't elaborate on this).

Another way would be to use the built in comparators, have one tied to below 3.3V and the other tied to a resistor divider on the 12V.

[image]
Source: https://www.latticesemi.com/-/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/ProductBrochures/AM/CommonAnalogFunctionsUsinganiCE40FPGA.ashx?document_id=45822